# Socket reading through buffered reader, not picking up on line

Tags: java, sockets

I'm testing out sockets so you'll have to excuse the messy code, but I'm having some problems just getting the socket server to pickup on a message sent by the socket, or perhaps sending the message. Either way, I can't figure out what's wrong.

My code gets up to the Listening for messages from attached socket point but not to the stopped listening point and there are no errors, so it is reading from the input stream. But when I write something in and it writes it to the OutputStreamWriter for the socket the buffered reader for the socket (Accepted by socket server) doesn't pick up on it.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

```
public class Main
{
    private static final String _address = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int    _port    = 8080;

    private static ServerSocket      _listener;

    private static Socket _socket;
    private static OutputStreamWriter _socketWriter;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Type something in to send it into the big wide world!\n\nType quit to exit.");
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Main._startListening();
        Main._connectToListener();

        while(true) {
            String msg = inputReader.readLine();

            if("".equals(msg)) {
                System.out.println("You can't send nothing!");
                continue;
            }
            else if("quit".equals(msg)) { 
                Main._listener.close();
                break;
            }

            Main.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending " + message);
        Main._socketWriter.write(message + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    private static void _connectToListener() throws Exception {
        Main._socket = new Socket(Main._address, Main._port);
        Main._socketWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(Main._socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Connected to listener");
    }

    private static void _startListening() throws Exception {
        Main._listener = new ServerSocket(Main._port);

        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Listening on " + Main._address + ":" + Main._port);

                while (!Main._listener.isClosed()) {
                    try {
                        final Socket socket = Main._listener.accept();

                        System.out.println("Attached new socket " + socket.getInetAddress().toString());

                        new Thread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                System.out.println("Listening for messages from attached socket");

                                try {
                                    BufferedReader socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                                    while(!socket.isClosed()) {
                                        String receivedLine = socketReader.readLine();
                                        System.out.println("Received " + receivedLine);
                                    }

                                    System.out.println("Stopped listening to socket " + socket.getInetAddress().toString());
                                }
                                catch(Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it. I need need the line terminator, but I also needed to flush the OutputStreamWriter after writing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Classic. You're reading lines but you aren't sending lines. You need to append a line terminator to the message.

Comment: That hasn't fixed it, I've updated the code in the op